# How do I turn AR mode off when the upper part of the screen is broken?

Tags: pokemon-go

The upper part of my screen is broken and I don't want to use the AR mode, because it takes too much battery.

Does anyone know how to turn of the AR mode, without having to click on the AR mode button while catching a Pokemon?

Comment: I tried testing what it would do if I removed the permission for it to use my camera hoping it would just kick it out of AR but instead it stayed on and everything was simply white besides the Pokemon. I know that isn't an answer but at least it's one less thing to try.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning what type of phone you're on, as some of the answers may be phone specific.

Answer (score 7):

You need **zoom**. During an encounter, zoom will move the AR setting down far enough for you to disable the option.

---

### [Android](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6006949?hl=en)

Go to Settings > Accessibility > Magnification gestures.
Set the switch to the on or off position.
When magnification gestures are enabled, you can magnify, pan, and zoom in the following ways:

- Zoom in or out by triple-tapping the screen. Then, while zoomed in,
  you can:

  - Drag two or more fingers to pan across the screen.
  - Pinch two or more fingers together or spread them apart to adjust the zoom level.
  - Note: If you enter or exit an app when zoomed in, you automatically zoom out. Simply triple-tap to zoom in again.

### [iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204390)

**Note:** for iPhone 6 and above, using **Reachability** by double tapping the home button will bring down the screen adequately. You can find this setting under the interaction heading inside accessibility.

Tap Settings > General > Accessibility to find zoom

- To turn on Zoom, use three fingers and double-tap the screen.
- To increase the level of Zoom, use three fingers to double-tap and hold, then move your fingers up or down on the screen to increase or decrease magnification.

Comment: iPhone: Just double tap home button? The screen will go down

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 good point, I've added that

Answer (score 1):

I've looked through the settings but that option only appears when attempting to catch Pokemon and when clicking on a gym to train or battle.

I don't know if there would be a way to make your phone "flip' the app though. I've never encountered/looked for one, but I'd *guess* it's possible if you have an Android phone and the know-how.